# Cannot get content of specific div with html agility pack

Tags: c#, regex, html-agility-pack

I'm using html agility pack for take some data from a website, now there is a bit problem. I want get some data from this div:

```
<div class="container middle">
<div class="details clearfix">
  <dl>
    <dt>Gara</dt>
    <dd><a href="/national/china-pr/csl/2016/regular-season/r34227/">Super League</a></dd>

    <dt>Data</dt>
    <dd><a href="/matches/2016/07/02/"><span class='timestamp' data-value='1467459300' data-format='d mmmm yyyy'>2 luglio 2016</span></a></dd>

    <dt>Game week</dt>
    <dd>15</dd>

    <dt>calcio di inizio</dt>
    <dd>
      <span class='timestamp' data-value='1467459300' data-format='HH:MM'>13:35</span>
      (<span class="game-minute">FP'</span>)
    </dd>
  </dl>
</div>
```

the problem's that there are two div with the class `container middle` and `details clearfix`, I want get the content onlhy of the specific div pasted above. This div have a dl tag for each tag.

This is my code:

```
var url = "http://it.soccerway.com/matches/2016/07/02/china-pr/csl/henan-jianye/beijing-guoan-football-club/2207361/";

var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(new WebClient().DownloadString(url));
var infoDiv = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='block_match_info real-content clearfix ']");
var matchDetails = infoDiv.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='container middle']");
```

and this return a wrong result, in particular this:

```
<div class="container middle">
<h3 class="thick scoretime score-orange">
  0 - 0
</h3>
```

this is the complete [source](http://pastebin.com/iXdGvtrw) code.

Comment: What exactly do you want to get ? The inner HTML of the <div class="details clearfix"> ?

Comment: Looking at your code and a complere source, I would say, that you were getting exactly what you want. Wait... I've just saw that there a two `<div class="container middle">`. And you want to get that second `div`, right?

Comment: @spirit, yes I'm also interested how to get this specific content: `<dt>calcio di inizio</dt>
    <dd>
      <span class='timestamp' data-value='1467459300' data-format='HH:MM'>13:35</span>
      (<span class="game-minute">FP'</span>)
    </dd>`

Comment: from wich assembly did you using `HtmlDocument` class? `System.Windows.Forms`?

Comment: @spirit using HtmlAgilityPack; installed by nuget

Comment: ok. I'll take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could do the following, for this particular web-page:

```
        var matchDetails = infoDiv.SelectNodes(".//div[@class='container middle']");
        Console.WriteLine(matchDetails[1].InnerHtml);
```

and working with `HtmlNode` via `matchDetails[1]`. To retrieve other data you can use similar `xpath` requests, like:

```
    var infoDiv = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='block_match_info real-content clearfix ']");
    var matchDetails = infoDiv.SelectNodes(".//div[@class='container middle']");
    var dl = matchDetails[1].SelectSingleNode(".//dl");
    var dt = dl.SelectNodes(".//dt");
    var dd = dl.SelectNodes(".//dd");
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Count; i++) {
        var name = dt[i].InnerHtml;
        var value = dd[i].InnerHtml;
        Console.WriteLine(name + ": " + value);
    }
```

Of course, you need some check for the `NullReference` and stuff

Comment: is possible select all the dt tag inside container middle?

Comment: yep, `var dt = dl.SelectNodes(".//dt");` this is selection of all the `<dt>` tag

Answer (score 1):

Query `div` with class `details clearfix` should return the target `div` element. There is one crucial detail you need to be aware of though, 
that a `.` before `/` is needed to make the XPath relative to the context element referenced by `infoDiv`, otherwise the XPath will be evaluated on the root document context (as if it was called on `doc.DocumentNode` instead of on `infoDiv`) :

```
var infoDiv = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='block_match_info real-content clearfix ']");
var matchDetails = infoDiv.SelectSingleNode(".//div[@class='details clearfix']");
```

Comment: fixed my answer, tnx.